# Image that adjusts its height when page is scrolling down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I am looking for an effect that I have seen on numerous occasions and that can be seen on the second image on this website:

https://www.daviseyecenter.com/

The effect I am referring to is how the image moves down so that you can see more of the top part of the image. What exactly is this called and how would I go about replicating this effect?

Comment: I am looking for general info about it and the name of the effect. I do not want someone to code it for me.

Comment: According to their source, it looks like they're using this: http://codecanyon.net/item/slider-revolution-responsive-wordpress-plugin/2751380

Comment: Not sure there's a standard name for this but shouldn't be too hard - it's relative position scrolling - each element scrolls relative to the scroll bar at a different speed/percentage of the scroll position (the main text is 1-to-1, the background image maybe 2-to-1).  Use z-ordering to put the image behind or change background position on scroll.

Comment: @freedomn-m I am unsure of what exactly you are saying. I think I understand to a certain degree, though. I just tried searching for " relative position scrolling" and didn't really come up with anything. I didn't know the scroll could be manipulated. Could you please provide an example of how to setup the " relative position scrolling". Again, I am not looking for this to be done for me, just an example of the syntax.

Comment: You set the position relative to the scroll position.  Something like: `$(document).on("scroll", function() { var pos = /*getscrollpos*/; $("div1").css("top", pos + "px");$("div2").css("top", (pos/2) + "px"); });`  But just use the parallax plugin :)

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks for trying to help me understand it! I appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is a parallax effect or more specifically parallax scrolling.

I see you have a jQuery tag, [here is a link](http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/) to a jQuery parallax scrolling plugin. That page has demos of the effect as well as explanations for how to add the effect to your own site.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!